# Why can't I overload class constructors in ArgoUML

Tags: argouml

In ArgoUML, if I rigth clock on a class there's the option critique -> add constructor to item.But once added the constructor, the option add constructor disappears and I can't add another constructor, so I can't have a class with multiple overloaded constructors.
How to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go through `add -> New Operation` and name your new Operation as follows: `<<create>> CLASSNAME_OR_CONSTRUCTORNAME(YOUR_PARAMETERS)`

afterwards just delete the return parameter of the newly created operation.